# SSLException: HelloRequest followed by an unexpected handshake message

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a webservice over SSL using Apache Commons HttpClient 3.1, using this:

```
String url = "https://archprod.service.eogs.dk/cvronline/esb/LegalUnitGetSSLServicePort";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
StringRequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity(requestXml, "application/soap+xml", "utf-8");
post.setRequestEntity(entity);
client.executeMethod(post);
String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

And I get this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: HelloRequest followed by an unexpected  handshake message
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1623)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:198)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloRequest(ClientHandshaker.java:286)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:114)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:525)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:465)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:746)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```

A request to the same URL on the same machine, using curl, works fine - and if I change the URL to e.g. https://www.verisign.com, it works fine in Java, too. So it appears to be the specific combination of Java and that host, not a general problem.

Ubuntu 10.04 beta, Sun JDK 1.6.0_19 (same problem in Ubuntu's bundled OpenJDK 6b18~pre4).

Any ideas what's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/11/14/ssl_renegotiation_bug_exploited/ for a discussion about why allowing unsafe renegotiation is not a long term solution.

Comment: My question is, does this mean that pre JDK 1.6.0.19, unsafe renegotiation was always allowed? Now with 1.6.0.19 we are forced to allow unsafe renegotiation manually?
Thanks for the insight ...

Comment: Yes, it would appear so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue as here, I think: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5435426

At least the solution works for this issue, too: add "-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true"

Answer (score 5):

We have a webstart application which fails because of this issue. The command-line version is working again when adding :

java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");

But the webstart version seems to ignore this, and until now we haven't foud a way to set this property in the webstart version.

Answer (score 2):

At least the solution works for this issue, too: add "-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true"

Thank you very very very much for that! 
I was trying to use maven deploy through an SSL connection, using certificates and I had the same exception. Now it is solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some updates to this - Oracle [has this KB that discusses the problem](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tlsreadme2-176330.html).

We've come across with with JRE 1.6.0_20 on Windows 7, but upgrading to 1.6.0_25 has resovled the problem (I realise there are later versions, however in the interests of software testing we're testing with a range of versions - this is the earliest we've been able to lay our hands on).