# 301/302 Redirect not working in Android (work differently in different versions)

Tags: java, android, redirect, http-status-code-301, urlconnection

When using a URLConnection, the 301 redirect doesn't work, doesn't even show a `Location` header, using getHeaderFields(). It is a blank list, except in newer Android (I tested 4.1 and it worked). It looks like something this has been reported in the default browser [here](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/356399-htc-hd-native-browser-ignores-301-redirect.html) as well, though in my test it worked in the Android browser. Is there some workaround for this bug in older Android?

I tried:

```
URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
(conn).setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
```

but it still returns an empty list, except in newer Android.

**Update**: It may be a related issue, it seems sometimes the URLConnection isn't even sending a request in some cases. (I checked with Wireshark on a pc with emulator). Is there a way to work-around this bug?

**Update**: I tried testing for 3xx redirect, redirects worked fine, but normal links didn't work with Ian's Cookie Manager. After making sure the setCookies was called directly after openConnection, it works great:

```
        URL u = new URL(_url);
        ...
        int tries = 4;
        int code = 301;
        URLConnection conn = null;
        while (tries > 0 && code/100 == 3) {
            conn = null;
            conn = u.openConnection();
            _CM.setCookies(conn);
            ((HttpURLConnection)conn).setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);//Required
            code =((HttpURLConnection)conn).getResponseCode();
            if (code/100 == 3) {
                String loc = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
                u = new URL(loc);
            }
        }

        //conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        conn.connect();
        _CM.storeCookies(conn);
```

The really strange thing is, for newer Android (4.1 emulator) the FollowRedirect line (commented "Required") is not necessary. On older Android (2.2), it gives `Connection Reset by Peer` error. This was probably the reason my redirect experimental code was failing on 2.2, not 4.1. Any reason for the differences in functionality? According to [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606873/sslexception-hellorequest-followed-by-an-unexpected-handshake-message), redirection https apparently has different behavior depending on the JVM version, could it be that Android's URLConnection/HTTPUrlConnection has changed in different versions as well?

Comment: You said HTTP request sometimes doesn't reach the server, what is the HTTP response code `conn.getResponseCode();` when redirect does't happen?

Comment: The method getResponseCode() is undefined for the type URLConnection

Comment: Using `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode();` when dealing with http related problem, I would always get and check the actual response code before doing anything further.

Comment: Apparently you have to re-set the `conn` after each redirect, was why double redirect wasn't working. Good workaround. Why does the default behavior not include this though?

Comment: Try using `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects();`, [Android API Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) is not accurate, check out [Java API Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) too see the difference between these two methods.

Comment: Good idea, it seems to work for all redirects now but not normally, unfortunately. (See code sample)

Comment: What method you are using `HttpURLConnection.getRequestMethod();` GET or POST?

Comment: A web agent regardless of HttpUrlConnection or HttpClient should by default automatically handle the redirect response if the original request use method GET or HEAD, if it doesn't, I would consider it as a defect or bug. check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341475/getting-url-after-a-redirect-using-httpclient-executehttpget/10342229#10342229) for more details.

Comment: Looks like user is supposed to ok a 302 redirect (not automatic)? Thanks for the link.

Comment: You've provided some helpful info, @yorkw could you expand your answers to an answer below?

Comment: I write comments only simply because I don't have a fully overview and understanding on your question. Feel free to use any helpful pieces and answer it yourself, I would like to vote your answer if you can provide one.

Comment: The code above is the "answer", the question now is why does Android do this? Anyway I can't bounty my own answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about URLConnection, but I know that HttpClient honors redirects and we use it all the way back to Android 2.1

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

(Based on apache commons HttpClient)

Comment: I've used that on an earlier problem due to a limitation of UrlConnection, I'd rather not rewrite it all though.

Comment: Does it support https? cookies?

Comment: I don't know what it does not support ;)